# Manually update a collection of Entity in FOs:Elastica

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I've an Entity strain that have a collection of Locus Entities. I use Elasticsearch to index the Locus Documents (in each locus document I refer to a Strain attribute).

I would want do something like: when the user edit the Strain entity, it manually re-index (update) all the Locus documents (because I need to update the Strain attribute in all Locus Documents).

To do it I've choose to use a Listener on the Doctrine PostUpdate event, and check if it's a Strain object. But I don't know how to ask to elasticsearch the reindexation on my objects.
Someone know how to do it ?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Strain;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class StrainListener
{
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $strain = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$strain instanceof Strain) {
            return;
        }

        $locusList = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Locus')->findLocusFromStrain($strain);

        // A command that ask to Elasticsearch reindex Locus

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've find a solution: ObjectPersister (FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister) with the method: ->replaceMany(array);

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Strain;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister;

class StrainListener
{
    private $objectPersister;

    public function __construct(ObjectPersister $objectPersister) {
        $this->objectPersister = $objectPersister;
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $strain = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$strain instanceof Strain) {
            return;
        }

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $locusList = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Locus')->findLocusFromStrain($strain);

        $this->objectPersister->replaceMany($locusList);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we just add the new array of posted elements to our mapping without re mapping the hole document ?

Comment: Do you declare anything in services.yaml?